# Blender Asset Browser: Change which side of object is previewed?

Tags: objects, interface, asset-browser, asset

I'm really enjoying organizing my Blender assets via the Blender Asset Browser. One unfortunate thing is that when generating previews of objects, the Asset Browser tends to generate previews of the backs, i.e., least interesting sides of the objects. (See screenshot).

Is there something I can change in how the Asset Browser generates previews?

or

Is there something I can change about the geometry of the objects so that the previews are more informative?

Thanks. Blender 3.1.2, Windows 11

[image]

Comment: Currently it seems that it is hardcoded to take the thumbnail of the object from - global Y axis, slightly rotated towards +X and +Z. So you either have to rotate every object 180° along global Z axis and apply the rotation after setting the origin point to individual origins (which will mess up your files if these objects are already used as links), or render custom previews and select them afterwards, which will be very time consuming

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is what I thought. As the Assets Browser is a work in progress I'll hold and see if the Blender folks address this.

Comment: As far as I know this is in the works. I think users will be able to choose custom scenes to render their assets